# Performance issue with clustered index for changing date column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, performance, time, clustered-index

We are using SQL Server 2008 Enterprise version. We have a large table FooTable (billions of rows).

FooTable Columns: `site:varchar(7), device:varchar(7), time(datetime), value(float)`

Every day we insert millions of new rows.

We created a clustered index for `site`, `device` and `time` (in order).

As we can see, `site` and `device` are relatively constant, but `time` will keep changing as time goes by.

The queries executed against this table would be:

1. `INSERT INTO FooTable SELECT * FROM #BULK_INSERTED_TEMP_TABLE`
2. `SELECT value FROM FooTable WHERE site = 'fooSite' AND device = 'fooDevice' AND time = 'fooTime'`
3. `SELECT SUM(value) FROM FooTable WHERE site = 'fooSite' AND device = 'fooDevice' AND time > 'startTime' AND time <= 'endTime'`

What is the best clustered index design?

Comment: Impossible to say for sure without knowing anything about the queries that access the table. `site, device, time` will lead to fragmentation though.

Comment: Can you show us the **table structure** (datatypes are important!! Not just column names.....) Also: what kind of **queries** so you expect on that table?? What kind of other indices (nonclustered ones) do you have - and how many??

Comment: +1. Also what softwaer? Enterpise edition? you may want to use a partitioned table by site... takin that out of the index ;) Needs enterprise edition, though, to use partitioend tables.

Comment: I've added more information, sorry guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no one true answer for the best clustered index design. In general, I look at clustered indexes two ways. First, they store the data, so you need to consider them from the data storage aspect. Are you creating a cluster that is likely to be constantly splitting pages as new data arrives? Second, because they store data, you should consider the queries that are going to be used most frequently to retrieve the data. Will those queries be able to use the clustered index to get at the data?

Knowing next to nothing about your set up, do you have an optimal choice for clustered index? I would say possibly not. What you've defined is a valid primary key candidate, but the structure you've outlined, with the two columns that are going to group the data into a particular structure combined with an ever increasing piece of data which will cause insertions all over the place within the distribution of the first two columns suggests you're going to be looking at lots of page splits. That may or may not be an issue, but it's something you'll need to monitor.

Comment: I mainly focus on the performance, although space should also be considered but relatively not as important as performance. Because those 3 columns cover 99% of the daily usage, we have to use them all together. But for fragment, page split, sorting while new records arrive, they might be a performance hit

Comment: Space wasn't in my considerations. Fragmentation on the indexes will increase space, yes, but it's the performance hit that's the bigger concern here. Not knowing your data, I can't tell you how big that hit will be, but it's something I'd focus on in my evaluations.

Comment: Based on the queries you've added, yeah, probably that's the clustered key I'd use too, but again, you might be looking at lots of page splits. Another performance issue is the act of rearranging the pages, something else to monitor for when you test the design.

Comment: What will be difference if I change the order of the clustered index from "site, device, time" to "time, device, site" (in order)

Comment: The distribution of the cluster will change since the leading edge will sort all new rows towards the end, almost like an identity column. You'll see less splitting of older pages since those values are set. Best answer though is, test it. Record a production session and play it back with different index structures. Observe the results.